# Python noisereduce package ImportError: cannot import name 'stft' from 'librosa'

Tags: python, importerror, librosa

Trying to import noisereduce

```
import noisereduce as nr
```

produces the following error, seemingly related to librosa:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "someFile.py", line 4, in <module>
    import noisereduce as nr
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/noisereduce/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from noisereduce.noisereduce import reduce_noise
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/noisereduce/noisereduce.py", line 1, in <module>
    from noisereduce.spectralgate.stationary import SpectralGateStationary
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/noisereduce/spectralgate/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .nonstationary import SpectralGateNonStationary
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/noisereduce/spectralgate/nonstationary.py", line 3, in <module>
    from librosa import stft, istft
ImportError: cannot import name 'stft' from 'librosa' (.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/librosa/__init__.py)
```

I have installed packages from

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the noisereduce package, but the error persists. Any suggestions?